# Maven-javadoc-plugin's "aggregate" goal and phase

Tags: java, maven, maven-javadoc-plugin

I have a multimodules project:

```
parent
  |____ module1
  |____ module2
  |____ module3
```

I want to generate *aggregated* Javadoc for all the modules. This works by using something like this in the `parent`'s pom.xml (which has a *pom* packaging and defines the children modules):

```
//...
<modules>
    <module>module1</module>
    <module>module2</module>
    <module>module3</module>
</modules>
//...
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>aggregate</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>aggregate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The aggregated Javadoc is generated correctly, that works well!

But the problem is that **I need to include the generated aggregated Javadoc in the `module3` final .jar**! In other words, I want the resulting `module3.jar` to contain a copy of that generated aggregated Javadoc of all the modules!

That's why I try to run the `maven-javadoc-plugin` plugin at the *prepare-package* phase in the `parent` project: I'd like the Javadoc to be generated *before* the packaging of `module3` is done, so I can include it (by copying it using a `maven-antrun-plugin` plugin, for example).

But, and here's my problem, it seems that even if I use the *prepare-package* phase, the aggregated Javadoc is not generated yet when the `package` phase is run for the `module3` artifact! It's like if the parent plugin is run *after* all the children plugins, even if it is declared using a phase which is supposed to be run *before*...

Any idea on how I could generate the aggregated Javadoc for all the modules *before* the `package` phase of the `module3`, so I can include that Javadoc?

Answer (score 0):

I wish someone finds a better solution, but here's the workaround I did, if it can help someone one day:

I do not let Maven generate the aggregated Javadoc by itself. I prevent that by wrapping the `maven-javadoc-plugin` plugin in a `<profile>`. I gave an "aggregatedJavadoc" id to mine.

Then, in module3's `pom.xml`,  I added a `exec-maven-plugin` plugin that, ultimately, programatically calls the `aggregate` goal, in the "aggregatedJavadoc" profile, on the parent module, at the `prepare-package` phase! Then I copy the resulting Javadoc to the build output folder of the `module3` module, so it is included in the resulting .jar.

The script that is called by the `exec-maven-plugin` plugin is custom in my case, but many solutions can be use to programmatically call the target Maven goal: [Apache Maven Invoker](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-invoker/index.html), for example.